# pass secureString parameter with invoke-expression

Tags: powershell

I want to pass parameter in another ps1 file, but I have problem to send parameter

my code:

```
#loginWindow.ps1

 $userName=$var_txt_username.Text
   [SecureString] $password=ConvertTo-SecureString $var_txt_password.Password -AsPlainText -Force
   $myPath="$path\MainWindow.ps1"
   $window.Close()
   Invoke-Expression "$myPath $userName $password"
```

---

```
 #MainWindow.ps1
 param(
 [string]$userName ,
 [secureString]$password
 )
```

and my error :

Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'password'. Cannot convert the "System.Security.SecureString" value of type"System.String" to type "System.Security.SecureString".

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is with `Invoke-Expression`, a cmdlet you should always try to avoid. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/9898643)

You can run your MainWindow script either by dot-sourcing it:

```
. $myPath $userName $password
```

or by using the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#call-operator-)

```
& $myPath $userName $password
```